# Download S3 File in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, amazon-s3, download

I have below code to download file from S3

```
 public FileStreamResult Index(string key, string fileName)
        {          

            GetObjectResponse resp = ReadS3Object("data", key);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.ResponseStream);

            var filresult = File(resp.ResponseStream, resp.ContentType);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName);
            Response.Flush();
            return filresult;

        }
```

and Ajax call like below

```
 $.ajax(
         {
             url: '/DownloadEstimation/Index',
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             datatype: 'json',
             data: {
                 key: key,
                 fileName: fname
             },
             type: "GET",
             success: function () {
                   window.location = '/DownloadEstimation/'+ key + '/' + fname;
             }
         });
```

But it just call method, not prompting user to save the file

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How is it duplicate. the scenario is different, I am trying code base but not working

Comment: The answers clearly state that you **cannot** use ajax to download a file using ajax. Use `location.href='/DownloadEstimation/Index?key=xx&fileName=yy`

Comment: that I tried,but its not downloading file

Comment: Your edit shows your url would not call the `Index` method (and do have a route definition for that method?). And there is no point calling the method twice. Just use the code in my previous comment (not in an ajax call)